# Android code after socket init not called

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking

I am currently starting a Thread on my device to communicate with my server.

The problem is that the code statement after the socket init is never called:

```
@Override
public void run(){
    try{
        socket = new Socket(context.getString(R.string.host), context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.port));
        Log.d("AppTest", "ActivityStart");
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        while(true){
            if(socket != null){
                if(awaitingString != null){
                    out.println(awaitingString);
                    out.flush();
                    awaitingString = null;//Reset awaiting string
                }
                String line;
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    if(line != null){
                        answer = line;//Overwrite answer
                    }
                }
            }else{
                socket = new Socket(context.getString(R.string.host), R.integer.port);
                out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In the debug I should be able to AppTest: ActivityStart, but it's not showing up.

PS: I am using the IPv4 address of my computer as host

Comment: Make sure you have enabled logging

Comment: @Mehdi If i place it above the socket statement, it's working fine

Comment: Please make sure that the host/port are working, maybe the socket is trying to connect to a wrong host/port

Comment: @Mehdi I also checked that, there's no error on that matter of fact

Comment: There will be a SocketTimeoutException. In the catch block you should place a log statement.

Comment: socket = new Socket(context.getString(R.string.host), R.integer.port);
you shoud not be doing this R.integer.port gives the id. Can you log the output of your host/port and validate them

Comment: `socket` canny possibly be  null at the point you are testing it. Your code spins in a hard loop if `awaitingString` is null, and if it isn't it reads until the peer closes the connection. It doesn't really make much sense.